# Taking pictures for one’s husband

Tags: halacha, commentaries, sexuality, tznius-modesty

Would Jewish law prohibit or limit the types of pictures a wife could send to her husband in private? Assume that the means of sending the pictures would be secure and no one else would be able to see the pictures.

Comment: See SA 240:11 ...

Answer (score 6):

[Rav Berachos (Ben Ish Chai)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1759&st=&pgnum=150&hilite=) – והנה ודאי כי האשה הלוקחת צורתה על ידי המאכינה כנז״ל ועושים ולוקחים צורתה על כמה ניירות ומחלקים אותם לכמה בני אדם הנה הם מכשילים הרבים כי הצורה הזאת הולכת ממקום למקום ומעיר לעיר וממדינה למדינה ועיני הכל שולטות בה בין אותם שהם בני ברית ובין שאינם בני ברית וגם כל טמא לנפש והכל מסתכלים בה ובאים להרהורים לא טובים כי היצר מכשילן להביט ולחשב בתוארה ויופיה וזאת הצורה תשאר קיימת לדורי דורות כי האשה לקברות תובל והיא בתוך העפר ועכ״ז המכשלה הזאת תעשה פעולתה ולכן ודאי ראוי שימנעו הנשים מזה המכשול לבלתי יקחו צורתן על ידי המאכינה ואם היא לוקחת ונותנת לחבירתה **מי יודע ביד מי תפול אח״כ צורתה** ובפרט לאותם הלוקחים על כמה ניירות ומחלקים אותם לפעמים האשה במערב ואיש בליעל יראנה במזרח מרחק שנה ויותר וחוטא במראיתו ואין זה ראוי והגון לזרע אברהם יצחק ויעקב זיע׳א אשר שם ה׳ נקרא עליהן וזהו דרכן של גוים הפרוצים אך לא כאלה חלק יעקב זרע ישראל ברוך אלהינו שבראנו לכבודו

The Ben Ish Chai notes multiple issues with women modeling even not for men, including '**who knows where pictures will end up?'** All the more so nowadays where pictures travel further and faster...

Comment: I just saw your answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114363/21984 and I think you're correct over there. But here, I don't see how this addresses the question. The OP is discussing a secure way of sending pictures between husband and wife where it won't be seen. I don't think this Ben Ish Chai is relevant as a halachic guide between husband and wife (the OP asks about Jewish law; the BIC is at best a humra/mida tova/concern about women not sharing their picture.)