# Ben Ish Chai against taking photos of females?

Tags: women, pictures, contemporary-halacha

I heard that the Ben Ish Chai was very against having women in photos, so much so that a woman would even be taken out of Gan Eden a hundred years after her photo was taken if someone looks at it. Is this true, and if so, where is the source for this?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110647/16354 dupe?

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110654/13811) for a similar discussion

[Rav Berachos (Ben Ish Chai)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1759&st=&pgnum=150&hilite=) – והנה ודאי כי האשה הלוקחת צורתה על ידי המאכינה כנז״ל ועושים ולוקחים צורתה על כמה ניירות ומחלקים אותם לכמה בני אדם הנה הם מכשילים הרבים כי הצורה הזאת הולכת ממקום למקום ומעיר לעיר וממדינה למדינה ועיני הכל שולטות בה בין אותם שהם בני ברית ובין שאינם בני ברית וגם כל טמא לנפש והכל מסתכלים בה ובאים להרהורים לא טובים כי היצר מכשילן להביט ולחשב בתוארה ויופיה וזאת הצורה תשאר קיימת לדורי דורות כי האשה לקברות תובל והיא בתוך העפר ועכ״ז המכשלה הזאת תעשה פעולתה ולכן ודאי ראוי שימנעו הנשים מזה המכשול לבלתי יקחו צורתן על ידי המאכינה ואם היא לוקחת ונותנת לחבירתה מי יודע ביד מי תפול אח״כ צורתה ובפרט לאותם הלוקחים על כמה ניירות ומחלקים אותם לפעמים האשה במערב ואיש בליעל יראנה במזרח מרחק שנה ויותר וחוטא במראיתו ואין זה ראוי והגון לזרע אברהם יצחק ויעקב זיע׳א אשר שם ה׳ נקרא עליהן וזהו דרכן של גוים הפרוצים אך לא כאלה חלק יעקב זרע ישראל ברוך אלהינו שבראנו לכבודו

The Ben Ish Chai notes multiple issues with women modeling even not for men, including 'who knows where pictures will end up?' All the more so nowadays where pictures travel further and faster...

Comment: So does that mean you can never take pictures of females for any purpose?

Comment: @Adam that's what he says. Obviously most people don't hold of this position.

Comment: Even the Ben Ish Hai admits it's a chumra in general and permitted according to the basic Halacha. See https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Drawing_or_Sculpting_Forbidden_Images#Human_Images #5